# typescript extend type from super interface

Tags: typescript

image the following typescript interface

```
export interface Update {
  type: 'STATUS_UPDATE';
}
```

I would like to extend this interface and add another value to the `type`, like this:

```
export interface HttpUpdate extends Update {
  type: 'HTTP_UPDATE' | super.type;
}
```

So that the `HttpUpdate`'s `type` is of `HTTP_UPDATE | STATUS_UPDATE`

Is this somehow possible with Typescript?

Answer (score 0):

You could use generics like this

```
type BaseUpdateTypes = 'STATUS_UPDATE';
export interface Update<T extends string = BaseUpdateTypes> {
  type: T;
}

type HttpUpdateTypes = BaseUpdateTypes | 'HTTP_UPDATE'
type HttpUpdate = Update<HttpUpdateTypes>;

const update: Update = { type: 'STATUS_UPDATE' };
const httpUpdate: HttpUpdate = { type: 'HTTP_UPDATE'};
```

So basically, you are extending the type of the `type` property rather than extending the base interface per se. The `HttpUpdate` type in the example above is not technically necessary, but serves as an alias to make it more resemble your original code

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the TypeScript handbook > Object Types > [Extending Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#extending-types):

> The `extends` keyword on an `interface` allows us to effectively copy members from other named types, and add whatever new members we want. This can be useful for cutting down the amount of type declaration boilerplate we have to write, and for signaling intent that several different declarations of the same property might be related.

This means that any type that is created by extending another type must, by definition, always be assignable to the type that it extends. Another way to say this is to say that the extended type is a subtype, or a narrower type.

In the example you've shown, the `HttpUpdate` type is not a subtype of `Update` because its `type` property is a string union, and that string union is not assignable to the single string literal of the `Update` type. Trying to create the type using literal values in the playground reveals this problem:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoAcAmdLIN4BQyyYAnuhAFzIBEAygCoCCDqdA+qgAoAiLAojQDcBAL4ECoSLEQoAEmDDoM2XBAAekEJgDOaLDhR5kAegBUyflCgB7KEWKOnAP1dv3BAJLho8JMgByBSUVQwDkUAQ7KAgEMAAbUmQNLV0Inxl-ANDIAIA6BwZyCD0bGGR0WwooMkCyCnC4GPSogFt0HGAAI3iIAqciikD6ZlYObj4GQWQAH1o5BgYuTl4BGnDgPRAbMGQ4HR1gAHMQOB6UMBsSYuHGFjYVycF8hwGbgJoFpce1ja2dvYHY6nc4kK71FAfO5jH5TdZ5AAUACYACwAZgADABKZBmEwOCHUT6LZYTNazWjQh5kuEicRAA)

```ts
interface Update {
  type: "STATUS_UPDATE";
}

interface HttpUpdate extends Update { /* Error
          ~~~~~~~~~~
Interface 'HttpUpdate' incorrectly extends interface 'Update'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type '"STATUS_UPDATE" | "HTTP_UPDATE"' is not assignable to type '"STATUS_UPDATE"'.
      Type '"HTTP_UPDATE"' is not assignable to type '"STATUS_UPDATE"'.(2430) */
  type: "HTTP_UPDATE" | "STATUS_UPDATE";
}
```

Since that interface only has one property and you can't extend the interface to create the type you want, there isn't much use it extending it as-is... so — in order to help illustrate your goal — let's add another property to it: a `message` property that has a `string` value:

```ts
interface Update {
  type: "STATUS_UPDATE";
  message: string;
}
```

You could create a new type that copies all of the properties **except** the `type` property (by using the type utility [`Omit<Type, Keys>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys)), and then set its `type` property to a string union like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoAcAmdLIN4BQyyYAnuhAFzIBEAygCoCCDqdA+qgAoAiLAojQDcRZAFsIAZ0lwA5lWSSwUULJEBfAgVCRYiFAAkwYdBmy4IAD0ghMk5AHkxwMAB4zOCABpaZCjQA+fFE-BRoDBgYuTl4BGmQAHzQsTwBtGlCaAF0NLUwIBAAbOCgUBAB7ECVkAAtjUxTIaiMTD0gROtbGiAA6UNFiQeIAemGAPQB+Ak6G816JaTkIAaGR8amgA)

```ts
interface Update {
  type: "STATUS_UPDATE";
  message: string;
}

interface HttpUpdate extends Omit<Update, "type"> {
  type: "HTTP_UPDATE" | Update["type"];
}

declare const httpUpdate: HttpUpdate;
httpUpdate.type
         //^? (property) HttpUpdate.type: "STATUS_UPDATE" | "HTTP_UPDATE"
httpUpdate.message
         //^? (property) message: string
```

Another way to create the same type, but using type aliases might look like this:

> See [Differences Between Type Aliases and Interfaces](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#differences-between-type-aliases-and-interfaces) in the handbook

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=8&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqmAmBDY0C8UDeAoKVSQC4oAiAZQBUBBcmUgfRgAUARagUWIG4coBbCAM4DEAcwhEBwAE4BLAHYjuAX25Z80ABLBgYOEhRR0AeV4zgAHj3IIAGhLriAPigAyTD3VFiG8uUYMWdmIoAB9YBGsAbWIHAF1lVXgIAGMAG0QpaGSAezlJKAALbV0IlCItHSsUbiLK0ogAOnUeXFbcAHp2gD0Afixakv1G-iFRCBa2ju6+oA)

```ts
type Update = {
  type: "STATUS_UPDATE";
  message: string;
};

type HttpUpdate = Omit<Update, "type"> & {
  type: "HTTP_UPDATE" | Update["type"];
};

declare const httpUpdate: HttpUpdate;
httpUpdate.type
         //^? (property) type: "STATUS_UPDATE" | "HTTP_UPDATE"
httpUpdate.message
         //^? (property) message: string
```

---

Finally — If this is a pattern that you find yourself repeating, you could create your own type utility to derive a type that:

- copies all of the exclusive properties from the first type
- copies all of the exclusive properties from the second type
- defines the type of each common property as a union of the types from that property on the first and second type

That might look like this:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&jsx=4&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=66#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcDOBLAbhAPAFXAgBooAxDJYCAJwD4oBeAKCigG8oBtAaSgwB2sRKgAmeANYQQAewBmUQpFJTZCilVp0AugC5FRXtqgBfANzNmoSFACqAjNXgY0wQQHMCARlL4ATAwsbABkwsjo2Hj4PooBrFCh8OGYOAR+vl508aGcvPxC8MA0AIYIwLiq8rEq0lXROvrRRlAAPrHN5pbW0LZgosXUTBzx3foARADK+ACC+LYTAPq2AAoAIrMwYxZsALYQaGjF7hD6rjQeFp1WRFAAEsDAYL39g4x2Dk5wLm4Cns8DJA4UFGUDGt3w+GWSzWGzGpjoFmY4mQxRo0AQMgErigAAsHk8+gD9PdHv9qBY8aTCdQAHTdeJsRlsAD0zIAegB+ZiUgkvCA0vYHI4QBlMlnsrlAA)

```ts
type Exclusive<Type, Filter> =
  { [K in Exclude<keyof Type, keyof Filter>]: Type[K] };

type UniteExisting<T1, T2> =
  & Exclusive<T1, T2>
  & Exclusive<T2, T1>
  & { [K in Extract<keyof T2, keyof T1>]: T1[K] | T2[K] };

type Update = {
  type: "STATUS_UPDATE";
  message: string;
};

type HttpUpdate = UniteExisting<Update, { type: "HTTP_UPDATE" }>;

declare const httpUpdate: HttpUpdate;
httpUpdate.type
         //^? (property) type: "STATUS_UPDATE" | "HTTP_UPDATE"
httpUpdate.message
         //^? (property) message: string
```